# To conditions in excel

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula

I am trying to create a graph from my test results.

At the moment I have somthing like this.

```
=COUNTIF(E22:E36,I19)
```

I would like to do something like `=if=Test1(COUNTIF(E22:E36,I19))`

I have some results like so

```
**Test name** 
-------
Test1
Test1
Test1
Test1

**Result**
-------
Pass
Pass
Pass
Fail
Fail

**Total**
-------
1
23
4
5
5
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more clear?

Comment: I have a list of tests "Test1 Test2" and would like to dynamically count the results "Pass/Fail| from each test. Does this make more sense? :(

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Excel are you using? In Excel 2007 or later try COUNTIFS with an "S", e.g. assuming test designation (Test1, Test2 etc.) is in column D try

`=COUNTIFS(E22:E36,I19,D22:D36,"Test1")`

or in earlier versions of excel try SUMPRODUCT, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((E22:E36=I19)*(D22:D36="Test1"))`